# How to render Figma inside iframe in a VS Code Extension

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vscode-extensions, figma

I have created a VS Code extension through which I render Figma shared files inside web view. I have used iFrame to render shared figma url. Below is the code for web view content.

```js
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
  'figmaWebview',
  'Figma',
  vscode.ViewColumn.One,
  {
    enableScripts: true,
    enableCommandUris: true,
    enableForms: true
  }
);

panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent(fileDetails);

// ________________________________________________

function getWebviewContent({
  fileId,
  fileName
}: {
  fileId?: string;
  fileName?: string;
}) {
  const figmaURL = encodeURI(
    `https://www.figma.com/embed?embed_host=share&url=https://www.figma.com/file/${fileId}/${fileName}`
  );

  return `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>${fileName}</title>
    <style>
    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe
    src="${figmaURL}"
    allowfullscreen
  ></iframe>
  <style>
    iframe {
      border: none;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</body>
</html>`;
}
```

It opens a figma page in iframe and shows login screen, if we click on login it gives error saying allow-popups permission not set, tried explicitly adding it to sandbox attribute but still it gives same error, I think VS Code is restricting the popups.

[image]

I inspected the official [Figma for VsCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=figma.figma-vscode-extension) extension and found that they are setting the cookie before loading the figma url, but I am not getting enough resource on how to get the cookie from figma.

```html
<script nonce="">
      const iframe = document.getElementById('figma-iframe');

      window.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
        const {data} = message;

        if (data.type === 'LOAD_IFRAME') {
          document.cookie = `__Host-figma.integ=${
            data.data.cookieValue
          }; path=/; Secure; SameSite=None; __Host-figma.integ.mac=${
            data.data.macCookieValue || ''
          }; path=/; Secure; SameSite=None; `;

          const url = new URL(`https://www.figma.com/dev_handoff/vscode/${data.data.href}`);
          iframe.src = url.toString();
        } else if (message.origin === iframe.contentWindow.origin) {
          window.parent.postMessage(data, '*');
        } else {
          iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(data, 'https://www.figma.com');
        }
      });

      window.parent.postMessage({type: 'IFRAME_CONTAINER_READY'}, '*');
    </script>
```